# Multiclass classfication on small imbalanced data

Tags: multiclass-classification, imbalanced-data, linear-discriminant

I have a tabular dataset (very small for ML modelling) that consists of 19 samples which are divided in three different classes (Class_1 = 4, Class_2 = 10, Class_3 = 5) with 1828 features with numeric values. I want to perform multi-class classification on the data. In order to deal with the imbalance in the dataset, I used SMOTE for making minority classes balanced as majority class exclusively on the training set. For the classification, I used both simple model Linear Discriminant Analysis and used cross-validation to train the model. But I am still unable to make an appropriate model having efficient metric scores.

1. For simpler model, I used Linear Discriminant Analysis, I tried to add some noise to the data to avoid overfitting due to the small size of data.I get very optimistic values (1.00) for all the metrics (precision, recall, F1-score and AUC) after the cross validation on the LDA model. Further on the test dataset I get the similar  I used the following code:

```
x = df.iloc[:, 1:].values
y_data = df.iloc[:, 0].values

#Encoding the target variable
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
y_encode = labelencoder.fit_transform(y_data)

#Assuming 'X' and 'y' are your features and labels
y_binarized = label_binarize(y_encode, classes=np.unique(y_encode))
n_classes = y_binarized.shape[1]

#Scaling the features
scaler_xlsx = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))  
X_scaled = scaler_xlsx.fit_transform(x)

#Splitting the dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, y_encode, test_size=0.5, random_state=0, stratify=y_encode)

#Assuming y_train contains the original class labels
min_class_count = min([sum(y_train == i) for i in np.unique(y_train)])

#Now, use this to set k_neighbors in SMOTE, considering there should be at least 2 samples 
#(SMOTE's requirement) to use as the nearest neighbors.
k_neighbors = max(min_class_count - 1, 1)  # Ensuring k_neighbors is at least 1

#Apply SMOTE on the training data
smote = SMOTE(k_neighbors = k_neighbors,random_state=42)
X_train_res, y_train_res = smote.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)

#Add noise to the training dataset
def add_gaussian_noise(X, noise_level=0.5):
    mean = 0
    # Generate Gaussian noise
    noise = np.random.normal(mean, noise_level, X.shape)
    # Add the Gaussian noise to the dataset
    X_noisy = X + noise
    return X_noisy

#Assuming X_train and X_test are your original datasets
noise_level = 0.5 

#Add Gaussian noise to the training and test datasets
X_train_noisy = add_gaussian_noise(X_train_res, noise_level=noise_level)
X_test_noisy = add_gaussian_noise(X_test, noise_level=noise_level)

#Adjusting n_splits based on the smallest class size
unique, counts = np.unique(y_train_res, return_counts=True)
min_class_size = min(counts)
n_splits = max(min(min_class_size, 5), 2)  # Use the smaller of 5 or the smallest class size

cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=n_splits, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

#Variables to hold the sum of the confusion matrices
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()

#Iterate over folds, train the LDA and calculate ROC/AUC
for train_idx, test_idx in cv.split(X_train_noisy, y_train_res):
    
    # Fit the LDA model and get the score for the test fold
    lda = LDA()
    lda.fit(X_train_noisy[train_idx], y_train_res[train_idx])
    y_score = lda.predict_proba(X_train_noisy[test_idx])
    
    # Compute ROC curve and AUC for each class
    y_test_bin = label_binarize(y_train_res[test_idx], classes=np.unique(y_encode))
    n_classes = y_test_bin.shape[1]

    for i in range(n_classes):
        fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test_bin[:, i], y_score[:, i])
        roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

#Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test_bin.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])

#Aggregate all false positive rates
all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)]))

#Then interpolate all ROC curves at these points
mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
for i in range(n_classes):
    mean_tpr += np.interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])

#Finally average it and compute AUC
mean_tpr /= n_classes
fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr
roc_auc["macro"] = auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])

#Evaluation on the test dataset
y_test_pred = lda.predict_proba(X_test)
y_test_binarized = label_binarize(y_test, classes=np.unique(y_encode))
n_classes_1 = y_test_binarized.shape[1]

fpr_test_1 = dict()
tpr_test_1 = dict()
roc_auc_test_1 = dict()
for i in range(n_classes_1):
    fpr_test_1[i], tpr_test_1[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test_binarized[:, i], y_test_pred[:, i])
    roc_auc_test_1[i] = auc(fpr_test_1[i], tpr_test_1[i])

#Calculate micro-average ROC curve and ROC area for the test set
fpr_test_1["micro"], tpr_test_1["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test_binarized.ravel(), y_test_pred.ravel())
roc_auc_test_1["micro"] = auc(fpr_test_1["micro"], tpr_test_1["micro"])

#Aggregate all false positive rates
all_fpr_1 = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr_test_1[i] for i in range(n_classes_1)]))

#Then interpolate all ROC curves at these points
mean_tpr_1 = np.zeros_like(all_fpr_1)
for i in range(n_classes_1):
    mean_tpr_1 += np.interp(all_fpr_1, fpr_test_1[i], tpr_test_1[i])

#Finally average it and compute AUC
mean_tpr_1 /= n_classes_1

fpr_test_1["macro"] = all_fpr_1
tpr_test_1["macro"] = mean_tpr_1
roc_auc_test_1["macro"] = auc(fpr_test_1["macro"], tpr_test_1["macro"])
```